# Swift optional syntax

Tags: swift, option-type

I wrote some code that works, but uses a few too many forced unwraps. So I fixed it but there has to a better way...

```
var currentTask: Tasks?
var photoArray: [Photo]?
@IBOutlet var photoButton: [TaskImageButton]!

photoArray = Array(currentTask?.photos) as? [Photo]

if photoArray!.count > 0 {
   for i in (photoArray?.indices)! {
      photoButton[i].setImage(UIImage(data: photoArray![i].imageData!), for: .normal)
   }
}
```

My attempted solution:

```
if let photoArraySize = photoArray?.count  {
   if photoArraySize > 0 {
      for i in (photoArray?.indices)! {
         if let photoData = photoArray?[i].imageData {
            photoButton[i].setImage(UIImage(data: photoData), for: .normal)
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is your current task property `photos` returning?

Comment: `photo` is a one-to-many relationship between the entities `Tasks` and `Photo`. (One task can have many photos, despite my entity names. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way is to declare the photos array as non-optional

```
var photoArray = [Photo]()

...

photoArray = (Array(currentTask?.photos) as? [Photo]) ?? []

...

for (index, photoData) in photoArray.enumerated() where photoData.imageData != nil {
   photoButton[index].setImage(UIImage(data: photoData.imageData!), for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unwrap `photoArray` once and the rest of the code is much simpler:

```
if let photoArray = photoArray {
    for i in photoArray.indices {
        photoButton[i].setImage(UIImage(data: photoArray[i].imageData), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

If `imageData` is optional, then you need:

```
if let photoArray = photoArray {
    for i in photoArray.indices {
        if let imageData = photoArray[i].imageData {
            photoButton[i].setImage(UIImage(data: imageData), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

And the line:

```
photoArray = Array(currentTask?.photos) as? [Photo]
```

can probably be written as:

```
photoArray = currentTask?.photos
```

But without more details about the types involved, it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

This might be cleaner if you get the array out of optional first

Also you dont have to check if count is greater than 0 because if the array is empty (count = 0) then for loop wont even run.

```
if let array = photoArray {
    for i in array.indices {
        photoButton[i].setImage(UIImage(data: array[i].imageData), for: normal)
    }
}
```

I dont know about Photo class but if imageData is also optional then:

```
if let array = photoArray {
    for i in array.indices {
        if let photoData = array[i].imageData {
            photoButton[i].setImage(UIImage(data: photoData), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```